# The meaning of char *p_c = new char['1', '2', '3', '4'];

Tags: c++

Consider

`char *p_c = new char['1', '2', '3', '4'];`

Is this syntax correct? If yes, then what does it do?

I don’t know why, but compiler allows this syntax! What will it do with regards to memory? I am not able to access the variable by `*p_c`. How does one determine the size of and the number of elements present?

Comment: Please read up about the comma operator - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 16):

Your code is syntactically valid C++, if rather strange, and I don't think it does what you intended:

`new char['1', '2', '3', '4']` is evaluated as `new char['4']` due to the way the *comma* operator works. (The preceding elements are evaluated from left to right, but the value of the expression is that of the rightmost element.)

So your statement is equivalent to `char *p_c = new char['4'];`

`'4'` is a `char` type with a numeric value that depends on the *encoding* that your platform uses (ASCII, EBCDIC &c. although the former is most likely on a desktop system.).

So the number of elements in the array is whatever `'4'` evaluates to when converted to a `size_t`. On an ASCII system the number of elements would be 52.

Comment: Note that '4' must evaluate to a positive number.  (It's a character in the basic execution set.)  So whatever happens, the expression is legal.  (Other characters might be negative, so would produce and error at runtime.)

Comment: It's probably putting something like "but it almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to." somewhere near the top.

Comment: @MartinBonner: That's helpful. Presumably `char` must always be a `unsigned` type on a system with EBCDIC encoding. Else `'4'` (which has an unsigned value 244) would be negative and would thus convert to a very large `size_t`!

Comment: @MartinBonner negative indices do not necessarily produce an error, it will be converted to `size_t` and allocate a large amount of memory (whether that succeeds or not depends on system details of course)

Comment: Maybe he meant `new char[4]{'1', '2', '3', '4'};`.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for the *new expression* you used is something like:

```
identifier = new Type[<expression>];
```

In the *`<expression>`* above, C++ allows any expression whose result is convertible to `std::size_t`. And for your own expression, you used the comma operator.

```
<expression> := '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

which will evaluate every item in the comma list and return the last, which is `'4'`, and that result will be converted to its `std::size_t` value, probably (`52`); So, the code is equivalent to:

```
char* p_c = new char['4'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *p_c = new char['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
char *p_c = new char['4'];
```

because of [*comma operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). Comma operator evaluates its operant left to right and discards them except the last one (the right most one).

The character literal `'4'` has value 52 in ASCII (but your system doesn't *have* to use ASCII and neither is it required by C or C++ standards-- but almost all modern systems do use ASCII).

So, it's as if you used:

```
char *p_c = new char[52];
```